# Ruby Pry Debugging

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

Is the an elegant unobtrusive way to template methods as shown below? The idea is to "dynamically" insert binding.pry on errors inside methods to streamline debugging.

```
def foo  #regular method
 ...
end

def foo  #method changed to debug errors
 begin
  ...
 rescue
  binding.pry
 end
end
```

Comment: Try [`pry-rescue`](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-rescue)

Comment: Works exactly the way I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pry-rescue`](https://github.com/ConradIrwin/pry-rescue)

> `pry-rescue` is an implementation of "break on unhandled exception" for
>   `Ruby`. Whenever an exception is raised, but not rescued, pry-rescue
>   will automatically open Pry for you.